# Generic "Error" with no further message when trying to interact with ERC-4337 Entry Point from Remix IDE

Tags: remix, error, erc-4337, javascript

I try to learn basics of ERC-4337 standard, so I deployed a simplest possible example of a contract implementing account interface on Goerli testnet - it just has one operation that changes its internal state, allows everyone to do it as long as message sender is EntryPoint, and pays its own gas fee.
My contract code:

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.20;

    struct UserOperation {
        address sender;
        uint256 nonce;
        bytes initCode;
        bytes callData;
        uint256 callGasLimit;
        uint256 verificationGasLimit;
        uint256 preVerificationGas;
        uint256 maxFeePerGas;
        uint256 maxPriorityFeePerGas;
        bytes paymasterAndData;
        bytes signature;
    }

contract UserOpTest {

    uint256 private testdata = 0;
    uint8 private constant EVENTTYPE_USEROP = 1;
    uint8 private constant EVENTTYPE_VALIDATED = 2;
    uint8 private constant EVENTTYPE_EXECUTED = 3;
    uint8 private constant EVENTTYPE_RECEIVED = 4;
    address payable private constant ENTRYPOINT = payable(0x5FF137D4b0FDCD49DcA30c7CF57E578a026d2789);

    event log(uint8 eventType, uint256 indexed v);
    event logB(uint8 eventType, bool indexed v);
    event logUOp(uint8 eventType, UserOperation userOp, bytes32 userOpHash);
    event logRcv(uint8 eventType, address indexed addr, uint256 indexed v);

    receive() external payable {
        emit logRcv(EVENTTYPE_RECEIVED, msg.sender, msg.value);
    }

    function _requireFromEntryPoint() internal view {
        require(msg.sender == ENTRYPOINT, "wallet: not from EntryPoint");
    }

    function validateUserOp(UserOperation calldata userOp, bytes32 userOpHash, uint256 missingAccountFunds) external returns (uint256 validationData) {
        _requireFromEntryPoint();
        emit logUOp(EVENTTYPE_USEROP, userOp, userOpHash);
        (bool success,) = payable(msg.sender).call{value : missingAccountFunds, gas : type(uint).max}(""); //ignore failure (its EntryPoint's job to verify, not wallet.)
        emit logB(EVENTTYPE_VALIDATED, success);
        return 0;
    }

    function getTestData() public view returns (uint256) {
        return testdata;
    }

    function exec(uint64 _testdata) external {
        _requireFromEntryPoint();
        emit log(EVENTTYPE_EXECUTED, _testdata);
        testdata = _testdata;
    }
}
```

Then I tried to send a UserOperation to it (using my own EOA as "bundler"), sending a single UserOperation to EntryPoint's handleOps method:

```
const {ethers} = require("hardhat");

describe("UserOpTestEntryPoint", function () {
    it("test", async function () {
        const provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(window.ethereum);
        const address = '0x5FF137D4b0FDCD49DcA30c7CF57E578a026d2789';
        const abi = [{"inputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"preOpGas","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"paid","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint48","name":"validAfter","type":"uint48"},{"internalType":"uint48","name":"validUntil","type":"uint48"},{"internalType":"bool","name":"targetSuccess","type":"bool"},{"internalType":"bytes","name":"targetResult","type":"bytes"}],"name":"ExecutionResult","type":"error"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"opIndex","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"string","name":"reason","type":"string"}],"name":"FailedOp","type":"error"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"sender","type":"address"}],"name":"SenderAddressResult","type":"error"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"aggregator","type":"address"}],"name":"SignatureValidationFailed","type":"error"},{"inputs":[{"components":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"preOpGas","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"prefund","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"bool","name":"sigFailed","type":"bool"},{"internalType":"uint48","name":"validAfter","type":"uint48"},{"internalType":"uint48","name":"validUntil","type":"uint48"},{"internalType":"bytes","name":"paymasterContext","type":"bytes"}],"internalType":"struct IEntryPoint.ReturnInfo","name":"returnInfo","type":"tuple"},{"components":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"stake","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"unstakeDelaySec","type":"uint256"}],"internalType":"struct IStakeManager.StakeInfo","name":"senderInfo","type":"tuple"},{"components":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"stake","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"unstakeDelaySec","type":"uint256"}],"internalType":"struct IStakeManager.StakeInfo","name":"factoryInfo","type":"tuple"},{"components":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"stake","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"unstakeDelaySec","type":"uint256"}],"internalType":"struct IStakeManager.StakeInfo","name":"paymasterInfo","type":"tuple"}],"name":"ValidationResult","type":"error"},{"inputs":[{"components":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"preOpGas","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"prefund","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"bool","name":"sigFailed","type":"bool"},{"internalType":"uint48","name":"validAfter","type":"uint48"},{"internalType":"uint48","name":"validUntil","type":"uint48"},{"internalType":"bytes","name":"paymasterContext","type":"bytes"}],"internalType":"struct IEntryPoint.ReturnInfo","name":"returnInfo","type":"tuple"},{"components":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"stake","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"unstakeDelaySec","type":"uint256"}],"internalType":"struct IStakeManager.StakeInfo","name":"senderInfo","type":"tuple"},{"components":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"stake","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"unstakeDelaySec","type":"uint256"}],"internalType":"struct IStakeManager.StakeInfo","name":"factoryInfo","type":"tuple"},{"components":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"stake","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"unstakeDelaySec","type":"uint256"}],"internalType":"struct IStakeManager.StakeInfo","name":"paymasterInfo","type":"tuple"},{"components":[{"internalType":"address","name":"aggregator","type":"address"},{"components":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"stake","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"unstakeDelaySec","type":"uint256"}],"internalType":"struct IStakeManager.StakeInfo","name":"stakeInfo","type":"tuple"}],"internalType":"struct IEntryPoint.AggregatorStakeInfo","name":"aggregatorInfo","type":"tuple"}],"name":"ValidationResultWithAggregation","type":"error"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"internalType":"bytes32","name":"userOpHash","type":"bytes32"},{"indexed":true,"internalType":"address","name":"sender","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"internalType":"address","name":"factory","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"internalType":"address","name":"paymaster","type":"address"}],"name":"AccountDeployed","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[],"name":"BeforeExecution","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"internalType":"address","name":"account","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"internalType":"uint256","name":"totalDeposit","type":"uint256"}],"name":"Deposited","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"internalType":"address","name":"aggregator","type":"address"}],"name":"SignatureAggregatorChanged","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"internalType":"address","name":"account","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"internalType":"uint256","name":"totalStaked","type":"uint256"},{"indexed":false,"internalType":"uint256","name":"unstakeDelaySec","type":"uint256"}],"name":"StakeLocked","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"internalType":"address","name":"account","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"internalType":"uint256","name":"withdrawTime","type":"uint256"}],"name":"StakeUnlocked","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"internalType":"address","name":"account","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"internalType":"address","name":"withdrawAddress","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"internalType":"uint256","name":"amount","type":"uint256"}],"name":"StakeWithdrawn","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"internalType":"bytes32","name":"userOpHash","type":"bytes32"},{"indexed":true,"internalType":"address","name":"sender","type":"address"},{"indexed":true,"internalType":"address","name":"paymaster","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"internalType":"uint256","name":"nonce","type":"uint256"},{"indexed":false,"internalType":"bool","name":"success","type":"bool"},{"indexed":false,"internalType":"uint256","name":"actualGasCost","type":"uint256"},{"indexed":false,"internalType":"uint256","name":"actualGasUsed","type":"uint256"}],"name":"UserOperationEvent","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"internalType":"bytes32","name":"userOpHash","type":"bytes32"},{"indexed":true,"internalType":"address","name":"sender","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"internalType":"uint256","name":"nonce","type":"uint256"},{"indexed":false,"internalType":"bytes","name":"revertReason","type":"bytes"}],"name":"UserOperationRevertReason","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"internalType":"address","name":"account","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"internalType":"address","name":"withdrawAddress","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"internalType":"uint256","name":"amount","type":"uint256"}],"name":"Withdrawn","type":"event"},{"inputs":[],"name":"SIG_VALIDATION_FAILED","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"","type":"uint256"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"bytes","name":"initCode","type":"bytes"},{"internalType":"address","name":"sender","type":"address"},{"internalType":"bytes","name":"paymasterAndData","type":"bytes"}],"name":"_validateSenderAndPaymaster","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"uint32","name":"unstakeDelaySec","type":"uint32"}],"name":"addStake","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"payable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"account","type":"address"}],"name":"balanceOf","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"","type":"uint256"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"account","type":"address"}],"name":"depositTo","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"payable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"","type":"address"}],"name":"deposits","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint112","name":"deposit","type":"uint112"},{"internalType":"bool","name":"staked","type":"bool"},{"internalType":"uint112","name":"stake","type":"uint112"},{"internalType":"uint32","name":"unstakeDelaySec","type":"uint32"},{"internalType":"uint48","name":"withdrawTime","type":"uint48"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"account","type":"address"}],"name":"getDepositInfo","outputs":[{"components":[{"internalType":"uint112","name":"deposit","type":"uint112"},{"internalType":"bool","name":"staked","type":"bool"},{"internalType":"uint112","name":"stake","type":"uint112"},{"internalType":"uint32","name":"unstakeDelaySec","type":"uint32"},{"internalType":"uint48","name":"withdrawTime","type":"uint48"}],"internalType":"struct IStakeManager.DepositInfo","name":"info","type":"tuple"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"sender","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint192","name":"key","type":"uint192"}],"name":"getNonce","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"nonce","type":"uint256"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"bytes","name":"initCode","type":"bytes"}],"name":"getSenderAddress","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"components":[{"internalType":"address","name":"sender","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"nonce","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"bytes","name":"initCode","type":"bytes"},{"internalType":"bytes","name":"callData","type":"bytes"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"callGasLimit","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"verificationGasLimit","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"preVerificationGas","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"maxFeePerGas","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"maxPriorityFeePerGas","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"bytes","name":"paymasterAndData","type":"bytes"},{"internalType":"bytes","name":"signature","type":"bytes"}],"internalType":"struct UserOperation","name":"userOp","type":"tuple"}],"name":"getUserOpHash","outputs":[{"internalType":"bytes32","name":"","type":"bytes32"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"components":[{"components":[{"internalType":"address","name":"sender","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"nonce","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"bytes","name":"initCode","type":"bytes"},{"internalType":"bytes","name":"callData","type":"bytes"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"callGasLimit","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"verificationGasLimit","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"preVerificationGas","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"maxFeePerGas","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"maxPriorityFeePerGas","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"bytes","name":"paymasterAndData","type":"bytes"},{"internalType":"bytes","name":"signature","type":"bytes"}],"internalType":"struct UserOperation[]","name":"userOps","type":"tuple[]"},{"internalType":"contract IAggregator","name":"aggregator","type":"address"},{"internalType":"bytes","name":"signature","type":"bytes"}],"internalType":"struct IEntryPoint.UserOpsPerAggregator[]","name":"opsPerAggregator","type":"tuple[]"},{"internalType":"address payable","name":"beneficiary","type":"address"}],"name":"handleAggregatedOps","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"components":[{"internalType":"address","name":"sender","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"nonce","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"bytes","name":"initCode","type":"bytes"},{"internalType":"bytes","name":"callData","type":"bytes"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"callGasLimit","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"verificationGasLimit","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"preVerificationGas","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"maxFeePerGas","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"maxPriorityFeePerGas","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"bytes","name":"paymasterAndData","type":"bytes"},{"internalType":"bytes","name":"signature","type":"bytes"}],"internalType":"struct UserOperation[]","name":"ops","type":"tuple[]"},{"internalType":"address payable","name":"beneficiary","type":"address"}],"name":"handleOps","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"uint192","name":"key","type":"uint192"}],"name":"incrementNonce","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"bytes","name":"callData","type":"bytes"},{"components":[{"components":[{"internalType":"address","name":"sender","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"nonce","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"callGasLimit","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"verificationGasLimit","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"preVerificationGas","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"address","name":"paymaster","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"maxFeePerGas","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"maxPriorityFeePerGas","type":"uint256"}],"internalType":"struct EntryPoint.MemoryUserOp","name":"mUserOp","type":"tuple"},{"internalType":"bytes32","name":"userOpHash","type":"bytes32"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"prefund","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"contextOffset","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"preOpGas","type":"uint256"}],"internalType":"struct EntryPoint.UserOpInfo","name":"opInfo","type":"tuple"},{"internalType":"bytes","name":"context","type":"bytes"}],"name":"innerHandleOp","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"actualGasCost","type":"uint256"}],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint192","name":"","type":"uint192"}],"name":"nonceSequenceNumber","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"","type":"uint256"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"components":[{"internalType":"address","name":"sender","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"nonce","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"bytes","name":"initCode","type":"bytes"},{"internalType":"bytes","name":"callData","type":"bytes"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"callGasLimit","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"verificationGasLimit","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"preVerificationGas","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"maxFeePerGas","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"maxPriorityFeePerGas","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"bytes","name":"paymasterAndData","type":"bytes"},{"internalType":"bytes","name":"signature","type":"bytes"}],"internalType":"struct UserOperation","name":"op","type":"tuple"},{"internalType":"address","name":"target","type":"address"},{"internalType":"bytes","name":"targetCallData","type":"bytes"}],"name":"simulateHandleOp","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"components":[{"internalType":"address","name":"sender","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"nonce","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"bytes","name":"initCode","type":"bytes"},{"internalType":"bytes","name":"callData","type":"bytes"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"callGasLimit","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"verificationGasLimit","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"preVerificationGas","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"maxFeePerGas","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"maxPriorityFeePerGas","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"bytes","name":"paymasterAndData","type":"bytes"},{"internalType":"bytes","name":"signature","type":"bytes"}],"internalType":"struct UserOperation","name":"userOp","type":"tuple"}],"name":"simulateValidation","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"unlockStake","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address payable","name":"withdrawAddress","type":"address"}],"name":"withdrawStake","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address payable","name":"withdrawAddress","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"withdrawAmount","type":"uint256"}],"name":"withdrawTo","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"stateMutability":"payable","type":"receive"}];

        let ops = [{
            "sender": "0x210aaad5055797b14d7ec437d1dc55b5b55527b3",
            "nonce": 0,
            "initCode": "0x",
            "callData": "0xeedefb5b0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000003039", //12345
            "callGasLimit": 153438,
            "verificationGasLimit": 47346,
            "preVerificationGas": 44380,
            "maxFeePerGas": 1500000024,
            "maxPriorityFeePerGas": 1500000000,
            "paymasterAndData": "0x",
            "signature": "0x",
        }];

        let beneficiary = "0xe35476f2d912e58eD29c1973d427Db70B63C8447";

        const signer = provider.getSigner();
        const contract = new ethers.Contract(address, abi, signer);
        try {
            let tmp = await contract.handleOps(ops, beneficiary);
            console.log('tmp', tmp);
        } catch (e) {
            console.log('e', e.toString());
        }
    });
});
```

My output:

```
RUNS artifacts/build-info/test.js....
 UserOpTestEntryPoint
e
Error
   ✓ test (193 ms)
Passed: 1
Failed: 0
Time Taken: 201 ms
```

What is that "Error" I get from await contract.handleOps? I'm rather a newbie in that ethers api, but I tried it already with simpler contract methods (like ones taking only one uint256 param) and it always worked for them.

Also, I'm sure the data structure I pass is ok. If I mess with it, for example by deleting last byte of sender, I get more detailed errors, like "Error: invalid address (argument="address", value="0x210aaad5055797b14d7ec437d1dc55b5b55527", code=INVALID_ARGUMENT, version=address/5.7.0)".

Edit: I see there is something more in browser console, but still I don't know how to check at which point it was reverted:

```
MetaMask - RPC Error: execution reverted
{
    "code": -32603,
    "message": "execution reverted",
    "data": {
        "originalError": {
            "code": 3,
            "data": "0x220266b600000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000040000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001e41413430206f76657220766572696669636174696f6e4761734c696d69740000",
            "message": "execution reverted"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I see what happens here. Metamask can't estimate gas amount used. It works when I set it manually, like changing:

```
let tmp = await contract.handleOps(ops, beneficiary);
```

to:

```
let tmp = await contract.handleOps(ops, beneficiary, {gasLimit: 1000000});
```